# Why does $df(x,y,z)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

In a derivation for the formula $\frac{dR}{R}=G_F\epsilon$ it is given that:
$$R=\rho\frac{L}{a^2}$$
$$\ln(R)=\ln(\rho)+\ln(L)-2\ln(a)\tag{1}$$
I know that: 
$$\frac{d\ln(x)}{dx}=\frac 1x\therefore\,d\ln(x)=\frac{dx}{x}$$
and so from $(1)$ we can say that:
$$\frac{dR}{R}=\frac{d\rho}{\rho}+\frac{dL}{L}-2\frac{da}{a}\tag{2}$$
However they have ended up with:
$$dR=\frac{\partial R}{\partial \rho}d\rho+\frac{\partial R}{\partial L}dL+\frac{\partial R}{\partial a}da\tag{3}$$
which seems like a standard formula but I do not see where it has come from

Comment: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/why-df-f-x-dx-f-y-dy.540258/ This is the only information I have found on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept you are looking for is that of a *differential form*, and a link to it is provided with the relevant context in the article [Differential of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function).

Answer (score 2):

The formula for $df$ which is the total derivative of a function $f(x,y,z)$, $df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz$
can be thought of as a consequence of the multivariable chain rule: given $x = x(t), y = y(t)$ and $z = z(t)$, then

$$ \frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt} $$

Multiplying by dt (even though a lot of people don't like this way of deriving the formula for the total derivative, I thought that it's worth noticing) gives the formula above.

Answer (score 1):

$dR=\frac{\partial R}{\partial \rho}d\rho+\frac{\partial R}{\partial L}dL+\frac{\partial R}{\partial a}da$

is very much a standard formula.

$dR=\frac{L}{a^2}d\rho+\frac{\rho}{a^2}dL-2\frac{\rho L}{a^3}da$

Dividing the LHS by $R$ and the RHS by $\frac {\rho L}{a^2}$ gives:

$\frac {dR}{R}=\frac {d\rho}{\rho}+\frac{dL}{L}-2\frac{da}{a}$

Comment: do you know why this is true for a general function $f(x,y,z)$?

Comment: It is the definition of the total derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, the total change in $f$, $df$, is equal to the sum of the partial changes in each of the $x$, $y$, and $z$ directions. The partial change in direction $u$ would be equal to the rate of change of $f$ in direction $u$ (or $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$), times the change in $u$ (or $du$), making it $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}du$. Therefore, the total change is equal to the sum of these for $x$, $y$, and $z$, giving 
$$df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz$$
This isn't rigorous, of course.

Comment: Since each of the changes is perpendicular why would it not be the root of the sum of the squares of the partial change

Comment: @HenryLee The changes $dx$, $dy$, and $dz$ are perpendicular. However the changes in $f$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx$, etc. are not. Think about moving a tiny amount in each of the $x$, $y$, and $z$ directions. The function changes by value $df_x$ when you move in the $x$ direction, $df_y$ when you move in the $y$ direction, and $df_z$ when you move in the $z$ direction. The movements were perpendicular but the total change in the function's value is clearly just the sum of the three changes: $df_x + df_y + df_z$. The direction that you stepped in to make those changes doesn't matter.